# Laravel - Mutators for Auth::user()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying got get mutators working for Laravel's built in auth system.

Mutators only works for me when I'm doing a query from database using eloquent and then I pass the data to my views. It doesn't work when I get the value straight from `Auth::user()`.

For instance, to convert date to human readable using Carbon, I have to have this long line in my view.

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse(Auth::user()->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}
```

I would love to simply do `Auth::user()->created_at` or even `$created_at` and have a mutator convert that to human readable date.

So like:

```
 public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date) {

    return Carbon::parse($date)->diffForHumans();
}
```

Does anyone know how I can do this the best way?

Thanks guys!